# How to call functions without onClick in Qt .qml file?

Tags: qml

How to call functions without onClick in Qt .qml file?

```
Item {
    id: btnSk
    width: state == "wait" : lSkip.width + 3
    height: parent.height
    visible: player.iW

    states: [                   
        State {
            name: "skip"
            when: player.iWt < 0
            PropertyChanges {
                target: skip_layout
                visible: false
            }
        }
      ]

    MouseArea {
        id: wait_layout
        anchors.fill: parent
        visible: false

        onClicked: player.skipSmt();
    }
}
```

Need to call `player.skipSmt()` without `onClicked`. How can I do it?

Comment: Am I missing something here, or is there some reason you can't just use the onVisibleChanged property notification?

Comment: In that case you really need to describe the desired behavior here.  I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe onClicked: { player.skipSmt(); }?

Comment: Downvoted: cleary state WHY you cannot use `onClicked` and WHICH event should/could be used.

Comment: Some program show Ads in pre-play videos. I found how to show skip button immediately. Now I need skip ads WITHOUT using onClick.
So, I do not have access to other files. Just one .qml...

Answer (score 1):

If you want the function `player.skipSmt()` to be called on startup of your `Item` named `btnSk`, then you could do the following:

```
Item {
    id: btnSk
    width: state == "wait" : lSkip.width + 3
    height: parent.height
    visible: player.iW
    ...

    states: [
        // your states
    ]
    MouseArea {
    // your mouse area
    }

    Component.onCompleted: player.skipSmt()
}
```

**P.S.** this assumes that `player` is an `id` accessible in your `Item` named `btnSk`

**P.P.S.** *If this is not what you want, then you should pay heed to the comment given by MrEricSir!*

Comment: Some program show Ads in pre-play videos. I found how to show skip button immediately. Now I need skip ads WITHOUT using onClick. So, I do not have access to other files. Just one .qml...
And Component.onCompleted: player.skipSmt() don't work in this case.

Comment: Then consider editing your question stating clearly *when* you need the function you named to be called.

Comment: Ok, here is new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947283/what-expression-should-i-use-in-qt-to-skip-ads